# How to Integrate Twitter in Phonegap using InAppBrowser

Tags: cordova, twitter, phonegap-plugins

I have done twitter using childbrowser as now childbroser is deprecated.
so now this code is not wokring.
I had tried to find new code but not able to find any code with inapbrowser.

Please help me :(

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 2):

hi you can check tutorial related to twitter integration via child browser [here](http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Twitter-integration-on-PhoneGap-using-ChildBrowser-and-OAuth-for-iOS-and-Android-Platforms) 
, in this tutorial they provide good description, you can change the childbrowser with InAppBrowse check this [link](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/dev/doc/index.md) , both are same, you can instal inAppBrowser via CLI

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
```

replace

```
  cb = window.plugins.childBrowser;
```

with
      cb = window.open(url, target, options);

and `cb.showWebPage`  with `window.open`

like you can see the same events and methods.

Comment: Thanks For quick replay. But in here he had use ChildBrowser. I have to integrate twitter in latest phonegap 3.3 so in 3.3 childbrowser is not available......

Comment: change cb = window.plugins.childBrowser; with window.open, actually childbrowser and inAppBrowser s are same,

Comment: Hy tried but still not working ...do i need to include chilbroser.js ? Can you please give new code with inapp Please :(

Comment: Even I had changed cb = window.plugins.childBrowser;  to   cb = window.open(url, target, options); and then i alert cb then its fire error or what will be the url.

Comment: if u r installed plugin via CLI no need of including js file, check this https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/dev/doc/index.md

Comment: Yes I am Using CLI and i have not include any Js expect   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
      
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jsOAuth-1.3.6.js"></script>

Comment: HEllo,    I just interate all thing now i am able to open chilbrowser and then when i click on authorise app its not going back to app. what i have to write for redirection url... please help me

Comment: @Arjun T Raj The link that you have mentioned have been expired. Is there any other tutorial I can use to  work with inappbrowser instead of childbrowser?